# Uniform continuity preserving measure zero

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, uniform-continuity

Suppose $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[a,b]$ and $E\subset [a,b]$ such  that $\mu(E)=0$ (lebesgue measure) then prove that $f(E)$ is of measure zero.

What i have tried so far is :

As $f$ is uniformly continuous, given $\epsilon>0$  there exists $\delta>0$ such that for $x,y\in [a,b]$ with $|x-y|<\delta$ we have  $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$.

Let $E$ be a subset of measure $0$ then there exists an open  set $E\subset U\subset [a,b]$ such that $\mu(U)<\delta$..

I want to show that $f(E)\subset f(U)$ and that $\mu(f(U))<\epsilon$  concluding that $f(E)$ is of measure zero.

Now, there exists $c,d\in U$ such that $f(c)\leq f(x)$ and $f(d)\geq f(x)$ for all $x\in U$.. ***

So, we have $\mu(f(U))=\left|f(d)-f(c)\right|<\epsilon$ as $c,d\in U$ and $\mu(U)<\delta$..

So, $f(E)\subset f(U)$ and $\mu(f(U))<\epsilon$..

So, given any $\epsilon>0$ we have $f(E)<\epsilon$. Thus $\mu(f(E))=0$..

Please let me know if there are any gaps..

Thanks..

*** such $c$ and $d$ exists when $U$ is a closed set.. But i thought i can consider closure of $U$ and choose $c,d$ from closure of $U$.. I believe $\mu(U)=\mu(\overline{U})$

Comment: Take $U = \mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$, does it then hold that $\mu(U) = \mu (\overline{U})$?

Comment: Is that $U$ open? @NigelOvermars

Comment: What you're trying to prove is false. For example there is a (uniformly) continuous function from $[0,1]$ to itself that maps the Cantor set onto $[0,1]$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich : Is that so? :( So there must be some thing wrong in my proof.. Can you please let me know what is wrong there..

Comment: Well, one problem is there's no reason to think that $|f(c)-f(d)|<\delta$. Yes, $\mu(U)<\delta$ and $c,d\in U$. So what? That doesn't say $|c-d|<\delta$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich : As i have told if $U$ is open then we have disjoint union $U=\bigcup (a_n,b_n)$ and $\mu(U)=\sum |b_n-a_n|=\mu(\overline{U}) $ as $\overline{U}=\bigcup [a_n,b_n]$.. ??

Comment: @NigelOvermars : See if you can help me with this..

Comment: So what? How does that show that $|f(c)-f(d)|<\dellta$? (It doesn't. If you think it does, please write down the proof very carefully before asking again...)

Comment: I really do not understand what is wrong here.. Please the pain of helping me... As $f$ is uniformly continuous, $c,d\in [a,b]$ such that $|c-d|<\delta$ so we have $|f(c)-f(d)|<\epsilon$ @DavidC.Ullrich

Comment: I've explained what's wrong. It's not true that $|c-d|<\delta$. (The $\dellta$ in my previous comment was supposed to be $\epsilon$, sorry.)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich : I think i got it why $|c-d|<\delta$ need not be true... But you have asked me to check $|f(c)-f(d)|$ in your previous comment... So, here it goes.. Let $U=[1,2]$ and $[7,8]$ then $\mu(U)=2$ but $|7-2|=5>2$...